# How to get a answer marked as answered when the questioner doesn't?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

In addition to [Top Questions without accepted answer](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1602/top-questions-without-accepted-answer).

How to get a question marked as answered when the questioner doesn't? Can a moderator do this? Can it be voted for? I realize sometimes it's difficult to judge about certain subjects without the proper knowledge and you cannot always fully rely on up-votes only.

But on a QA site, nothing is more annoying if a question is highly answered, sometimes even with many up-voted answers and obviously also the correct answer. Still they seem to stay officially "unanswered".

For example, why can't a user loose reputation points for example when a question is unanswered for a month and the questioner seems inactive (about that specific question, or in general)?

It annoys me that I'm looking on my profile for the questions I asked and the answers I gave, and I see unanswered questions, that are open for a long time but that are actually answered. *If the question is actually unanswered, not answered correctly, it's a recent question, or it's just not decided yet than it's obviously completely fine when it is unanswered.*

Comment: As an aside, why do you have so many of your questions that have answers, but you haven't accepted any yet?

Comment: @RoryAlsop obviously because they are asked recently or I considered them not answered completely yet. I check that lists everyday. :)

Comment: Extrapolate across - the answers you have left on questions may not be complete answers in the OP's opinion as well...

Comment: @RoryAlsop touché

Comment: I'm wondering it StackExchanges sends an email reminder after some time to  new members who have asked a question which received answers but none is selected. It could be useful for people who come here with a precise question in mind, ask it, get their answer, and just do not know about the rest. Recently I just learned to a new member that he could upvote several answers, he was just unaware of that fact.

Comment: FYI, Off-topic: some of your editing activity is discussed [here](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/questions/2416/would-it-be-useful-to-invite-tag-wiki-edit-reviewers-to-check-for-possible-copy).

Comment: @S.L.Barth, Thanks, I will check it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It just means "accepted answer". That's a decision the OP gets to make.

MY annoyance is when the OP accepts an obviously wrong answer that is also downvoted heavily by the community, simply because the Answerer shares a common belief or prejudice as the OP.

But that's just how StackExchange works. The questions have been *answered*, they just need to be *accepted* by the OP.

Comment: So should I flag it and ask a moderator to accept an answer?

Comment: Nope - there is no method to do that. Only the OP can accept an answer.

Comment: WHY??? Don't drop your answer!

Comment: What impact does having unaccepted answers have on your profile? Your answers are a value *to the community*, not solely to you.

Comment: Green looks better than white in a list. Maybe I'll try to ping the OP somehow by making a comment with his name in it.

Comment: Or do you prefer to have all your answers shown as green on your profile?

Comment: @EvanderConsus Please do not delete your answers. Mods will come through and undelete them. Your answers are for the benefit of the community.

Comment: removing your answer actually hinders the community - removal of it is definitely not a good thing! That is much worse than the minor annoyance of a drive-by questioner not marking an answer as accepted

Comment: What looks good on your profile is your reputation. That's what the community as a whole thinks of all your submissions, whether accepted or not. Work on your rep and work on providing good content.

Comment: Ok, I won't delete my answers.

Comment: @schroeder http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/92574/what-is-the-purpose-of-subdomain-enumeration/92576. Not that my answer here is of much value. But the community answered the question clearly and it's a year old post.

Comment: @EvanderConsus: Don't forget to click on the "Show more comments" button, you will see the OP claims below each answer that it does not fully answer his question. *You* may not agree, but this the OP point-of-view!